# Text to speech not working on iOS in the background

Tags: ios, flutter, text-to-speech

I am unable to play an audio that is generated in the background using text to speech plugin [flutter_tts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts) on **iOS only**.

I am getting the following error:

```
2023-01-11 09:52:04.095673+0400 Runner[12016:2350386] [AXTTSCommon] Failure starting audio queue alp!
2023-01-11 09:52:05.218595+0400 Runner[12016:2350386] [AXTTSCommon] _BeginSpeaking: couldn't begin playback
```

**Background Settings in info.plist**

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>processing</string>
    </array>
```

**Speaker Configuration**

```
Future<void> initializeSpeaker() async {
    speakerPlugin = FlutterTts();
    speakerPlugin.setQueueMode(0);





    /////////////////////////////
    //Selecting voices
    ////////////////////////////
    var voices = await speakerPlugin.getVoices;

    //example {name: ur-PK-language, locale: ur-PK}



    String deviceLanguage= Platform.localeName.substring(0,2);
    int defaultvoiceix = 0;
    String userlocale = "en-gb";

    try {
      String languageCode = Platform.localeName.split('_')[0];
      String countryCode = Platform.localeName.split('_')[1];
      userlocale = languageCode + "-"+countryCode;
    } catch (exception) {
      userlocale = "en-gb";
    }

    for (var i=0;i<voices.length;i++) {
      String currentLocale = voices[i]["locale"];
      if (currentLocale.toLowerCase() == userlocale.toLowerCase()){
        defaultvoiceix = i;
      }
    }
    
    await speakerPlugin.setSharedInstance(true);
    await speakerPlugin.setVoice(voices[defaultvoiceix]);
    await speakerPlugin.setVolume(1.0);
    await speakerPlugin.setSpeechRate(1.0);
    await speakerPlugin.setPitch(1.0);
    await speakerPlugin.setLanguage(userlocale);
    await speakerPlugin
        .setIosAudioCategory(IosTextToSpeechAudioCategory.playback, [
      IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers,
      IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.duckOthers
    ]);

  }
```

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: Do you solve the problem my dude?